# Add multiple application and listeners to NGINX unit

Tags: python, http, nginx-unit

At first I setup application server like this.

`firstapp.json`

```
 {
      "listeners": {
          "*:8008": {
              "pass": "applications/first"
          }
      },
      "applications":{
         "first":{
              "type":"python 3.8",
              "module":"firstapp.wsgi",
              "home":"/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/firstapp/",
              "path":"/var/www/html/firstapp/current"
         }
      }
  }
```

`sudo curl -X PUT -d @/home/ubuntu/firstapp.json --unix-socket /run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config`

then I want to add `secondapp` setting,

`secondapp.json`

```
 {
      "listeners": {
          "*:8009": {
              "pass": "applications/second"
          }
      },
      "applications":{
          "second":{
              "type":"python 3.8",
              "module":"secondapp.wsgi",
              "home":"/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/secondapp/",
              "path":"/var/www/html/secondapp/current"
          }
      }
  }
```

`sudo curl -X PUT -d @/home/ubuntu/secondapp.json --unix-socket /run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config`

It could be registered but,It overwrites the first setting.

How can I add the seccond app to the setting???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
  "listeners": {
      "*:8008": {
          "pass": "applications/first"
      },
       "*:8009": {
          "pass": "applications/second"
      }
  },
  "applications":{
     "first":{
          "type":"python 3.8",
          "module":"firstapp.wsgi",
          "home":"/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/firstapp/",
          "path":"/var/www/html/firstapp/current"
     },
      "second":{
          "type":"python 3.8",
          "module":"secondapp.wsgi",
          "home":"/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/secondapp/",
          "path":"/var/www/html/secondapp/current"
      }
    } 
}
```

just combine them into one json

Comment: Thank you verymuch ,so I need to combine all the time I added the `server`?? However it is easy to understand , thank you very much